# How Can I Make an Age Restricted Site that brings people to another site if age is good?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dreamweaver

I want to create a small survey/questionnaire that asks the user whether or not they are older than 18. Once they press the Enter button, I would like to make two options. One: If they are not over 18, it will take them to another web page. And two: if they are over 18 it will bring them to another web page. 
It kind of reminds me of the "if" "else" statement in Java, but I know this isn't Java. I'm using HTML (Dreamweaver) and I can't figure it out. Can somebody point me to the right direction?

I've got the bare bone of it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>WAIT!</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>WAIT!</p>
<p>Let us know more about you.</p>
<p>Please fill out this form so that we can guide you to YOUR world. </p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Are you a:</p>
<form>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
</form> 
<p> Age: </p>
<form>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">
younger than 18<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">
18+
</form> 
<p></p>
<form name="input" action="#" method="get">
<input type="submit" value="Enter">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

To see the output, copy and paste above code and enter it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_loc_assign). Then press submit code.

Comment: Are you running _any_ sort of programmable server? What's handling the form submission?

Comment: @MattBall I dont think so, coz in that case question would have been tagged. Since this is tagged as dreamweaver and you can fairly assume about the question poser's skills.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample script that redirect users on checking what is selected in radio using javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>WAIT!</title>
</head>
<script>
function redirect() {
    if(document.getElementById("m").checked == true)
    {
        window.open("http://www.codeforbrowser.com")
    }
    else {
        window.open("http://www.yahoo.com")
    }

}
</script>
<body>
<p>WAIT!</p>
<p>Let us know more about you.</p>
<p>Please fill out this form so that we can guide you to YOUR world. </p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Are you a:</p>
<form>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
</form> 
<p> Age: </p>
<form>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" id="m" >
younger than 18<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"  id="f">
18+ 
</form> 
<p></p>
<form name="input" action="#" method="get">
<input type="submit" value="Enter" onclick="redirect();">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/LNpT6/)

Comment: @user1753668: you might want to accept the answer in that case.

Answer (score -1):

Give your form some id;

```
<form id="sex_form">
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">
younger than 18<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">
18+
</form> 
<input type="submit" onclick="validate()" value="Enter">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate(){
            var form = document.getElementById('sex_form');
            if(form.firstElementChild.checked){
            alert('to younger');
                            //window.open('younger');
            }
            else if(form.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.checked){
                            //window.open('older');
            alert('to 18+');
           }
            else
            alert('none selected');
        }


    </script>
```

Comment: This wasn't the kind of thing I was looking for but thanks for your input/help!